# Parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, parallax

I'm trying to make a parallax effect according to this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D75WTf_Y738

But my function doesn't apply to my objects.
Here's the function:

```
    function parallax() {
    var sphereOne = document.getElementById("sphereOne");
    sphereOne.style.top = window.pageYOffset +'px';
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
```

I know I can use hundreds of JQ libraries instead to achieve the effect, but want to understand what's wrong.
My objects just stuck at the same place when scrolling.

Here's the JSFiddle example:

jsfiddle.net/hkbusbkm

Comment: This isn't the final code that he uses. You need to divide the offset by some factor to slow down the rate of motion of the sphere. Watch the video to the end.

Comment: I did. I mean my code doesn't work from the very beginning (when it looks like above).

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle for this? Just so we can see it in action.

Comment: Here it is
https://jsfiddle.net/hkbusbkm/
But I am stuck at the very beginning of JS coding, because according to the tutorial, my "bird" supposed to get down while scrolling, but it stays at the same place.

Comment: The issue was in capital "S" in pageYOffset

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/eenaa63t/ I just made this for you. And search for Dev Tips on YouTube. He is a fantastic YouTuber, and teaches about everything. And, here is my jQuery code that did the work when you scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.logo *** OR WHATEVER IS BEING PARALLAXED**').css({
'translate' : 'transform(0px ' wScroll /2 '%)'
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this in pure CSS:

```
#selector {
    background-image: url('url.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```