# Scrolling effect for divs and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

it has a scrolling effect when you scroll down. Like when you scroll down, the div's and images all come into view with an effect. What is it called and how can i implement it?

**Edit**: Parallax scrolling is not what I'm looking for. Scroll down to the section where it says "Featured Properties" and then look at the 3 images that are displayed horizontally. If you scroll around that area, you will see the images having a sliding effecting into the position. How can I do that with `div`'s and images?

Comment: It's called parallax scrolling

Comment: http://materializecss.com/parallax.html So, 'parallax' is the word. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallax scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330564/parallax-scrolling)

Comment: @Kevin edited the OP

Comment: @nevermind edited the OP

Comment: @HParker edited the OP

Comment: That's just an offset fade-in... The opacity is originally 0 and as you slide down the images' opacity go to 1 gradually (all offset of course). The images also start with some y-offset to be positioned back where they need to be. You'll need to find with javascript where your user's y-position is and base your css on that. Googling about what I just told you should help you a lot, it's a popular effect.

Comment: Have you tried wow.js

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the fading effect: It could be achieved by connecting the opacity with the y value of the image and the the y pos of the document.

```
$(document).on( 'scroll', window, function(){
  var opacity = 0;
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var windowCenter = windowTop+(windowHeight/2);
  var windowBottom = windowTop+windowHeight;
  var imageCenter = $('#img').offset().top+($('#img').height()/2);
  if(windowCenter < imageCenter){
    opacity = ((windowBottom - imageCenter) * 2) / windowHeight;
  }else{
    opacity = ((windowTop - imageCenter) * 2) / -windowHeight;
  }
  $('#img').css('opacity',opacity);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c3fu0xnb/